# javascript check object exists

Tags: javascript, object, exists

I have following code to check the object whether exists for item listing.
For testing purpose, i only have one object `sub_total_0`, however the script keep looping because `typeof` cannot determine `sub_total_1` is undefined or not exists, and keep going 2,3,4,5,...

```
var i = 0;
while (typeof document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i) != "undefined") {
    var obj_sub_total = document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i);
    if (obj_sub_total != "undefined") {
        if (fr.order_method_id.value == 1) {
            obj_sub_total.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            obj_sub_total.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
typeof document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i) != "undefined"
```

and

```
if (obj_sub_total != "undefined") {
```

`getElementById` returns either `null` or an HTML element. Neither of these are the string `"undefined"` and the type of each of this will be `"object"`. Thus your conditions don't make sense.

You test for truthfulness instead. An HTML element will always be true and `null` will always be false.

```
while (document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i)) {
```

and

```
if (obj_sub_total) {
```

Answer (score 1):

[getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) return null if element is not found, and the type of `null` is object that is why your condition is not working.

You can just check whether it is a truthy value and since the while() loop validates the object there is no need for the `if` condition

```
var i = 0,
    obj_sub_total;
while (obj_sub_total = document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i)) {
    console.log(obj_sub_total)
    if (fr.order_method_id.value == 1) {
        obj_sub_total.style.visibility = "visble";
    } else {
        obj_sub_total.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    i++;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uh9a12db/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your check doesn't work because using `typeof` on `getElementById`'s return value will **always** give you `"object"`, because it returns `null` if it can't find it, and `typeof null` is `"object"`.

Just check the return value directly: If there's an element, it's a "truthy" value (one that coerces to `true` when used as a condition); if there isn't one, `null` is a "falsey" value (coerces to `false`).

So:

```
while (document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i)) {
```

You also don't need to look it up twice, which is what you're currently doing; instead:

```
var obj_sub_total;
while ((obj_sub_total = document.getElementById("sub_total_" + i)) != null) {
```

(You don't technically need the `!= null` there, but without it it looks a bit like you've accidentally used `=` where you wanted `==`.)

---

Another alternative would be to use a class and `querySelectorAll`:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".sub_total");
```

Then loop while `i` is `< list.length`, e.g.:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".sub_total");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    var obj_sub_total = list[i];
    // ...
}
```

Or you could do that even when using `id`s:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=sub_total]");
```